# Bit fields in C for signed integer-struct num { int a:3; int b:2; int c:1; }

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

I am getting confused with bit fields in C. Can anyone explain me the bit fields concepts or can anyone suggest me some good resources for understanding the basic concepts of bit fields in structures?

I have tried this program, but I cant understand the output.

In gcc 32 bit compiler

```
struct num
{
    int a:3;
    int b:2;
    int c:1;
};
void main()
{
    struct num n={8,-6,5};
    printf("%d\n%d\n%d",n.a,n.b,n.c);
}
```

Output: 0,-2,-1

Comment: unless you actually want the bit field to contain a signed value, always used 'unsigned'.   When using 'int' one bit is only used for the sign.  in the posted code, the field num.c can contain only the sign, not any actual value.

Comment: @user3629249: not quite.  In two's complement (which is by far the most popular representation these days) a 1-bit signed field can hold the two values `0` and `-1`.

Comment: regarding the line: 'struct num n={8,-6,5};'   this causes the compiler to issue 3 warnings about overflow of the field max value.    Always enable all warnings when compiling.  for gcc, at a minimum, use '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic'  Fix the warnings. (don't mask the warnings)

Comment: there are only 2 correct ways to declare the main() function:  1) 'int main( int argc, char* argv[])'  2) 'int main( void )'   and one optional/allowed way: 'int main()'.   I.E. all valid declarations have a 'int' return value, not a 'void' return value.   To avoid returning a random number to the OS, the last executable statement in main() needs to be a 'return value;'  where that value is usually 0, which indicates to the OS that the function executed successfully

Comment: @SteveSummit, Thanks for the clarification.   I have not used 'int' bit fields since back in school in 1973, so had forgotten that detail.  (normally, I want to handle bits in some hardware register, so always use 'unsigned' when developing bit fields

Comment: @user3629249: C language says that an `int` bit-field can be signed or unsigned, depending on the implementation. It is not correct to say that `int` bit-field will necessarily have a sign bit. For this reason it is indeed a good idea to explicitly state your intent with bit-fields: explicitly state either  `unsigned` or `signed`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay as you are a beginner, lets try to explain this..

The first one is `int a : 3` which means that you are interested to store 3 bits, but in the main you are assigning the value 8..
Now the binary value of 8 is 1000 but as you are considering only 3 bits, the last 3 zeros(0) are taken & the output is 0

Now the second one is `int b : 2` which means you are storing 2 bits. Now from the main you are writing -6. Now whenever any negative number is stored inside the memory, it is stored as `2's complement`. Hence the binary value of 6 is `00000000 00000000 00000000 00000110` and because it is a negative number, hence the `1's complement` is `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111001` and if you add `1` to it for `2's complement` it will be    `11111111 11111111 11111111 11111010`..Now because you are taking only 2 bits in the structure, hence last to bits will be the answer which is `10` or `2` and because it was actually a negative number hence the output will be `-2`

Now the 31st bit of the memory is already set hence whatever the new number you will give, it will take as a negative..Now c is of 1 bit & in the main you give 5 which is basically `0101` & hence it will be last 1 bit & hence the answer will be `-1`...

Hence your compiler is behaving normally..

Comment: Sarkar: Thank you.Its very clear.Thank you for explaining binary representation of these numbers.

Answer (score 2):

A bitfield is a "tiny" integer type for which you can directly specify the exact size in bits.  Bitfields can be used only inside structures.  The main uses for bitfields are (a) saving space in structures you'll have lots of copes of, and (b) attempting to confirm to externally-imposed storage layouts, e.g. device driver control-and-status registers or networking packets.

The code fragment you presented gives unexpected results because the number 8 (1000 in base 2) can't be represented in 3 bits, -6 cannot be represented in 2 bits, and 5 clearly cannot be represented in 1 bit.

Comment: Thanks.But some sites have  explanation and answers for these type of questions.Ok leave them.Can you explain me bit fields for signed integer apart from this snippet?.I want to know how the  negative numbers are represented in fields?Or suggest me some resource for better understanding.

Comment: Do a web search on "two's complement".  But basically: a 2-bit field can store 4 values, a 3-bit field can store 8 values, an n-bit field can store 2^n values.  If they're unsigned, the values range from 0 to (2^n)-1.  If they're signed, half of the values are negative and the other half are 0 or positive.  So a 3-bit signed field can represent integers from -4 to +3.

Comment: Thank you for explaining the ranges.But how the number '8' is taking a value of '0' from  the range -4 to 3?

Comment: User @AnT explained that in their answer.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, in bit-field declarations `int` does not necessarily mean `signed int`. In bit-field context signedness of plain `int` is implementation-defined. It is one context in C language when you have to explicitly say `signed [int]` if you want to ensure signedness of the stored value.

Secondly, apparently in your case `int` bit-fields happen to be signed, which means that on 2's-complement platform your bit-fields will have the following ranges

- a : [-4, 3]
- b : [-2, 1]
- c : [-1, 0]

You are assigning values that do not fit into these ranges, causing signed integer overflow. The outcome of signed integer overflow on assignment is implementation-defined. In your implementation the 2's-complement representation is apparently simply truncated to the number of available bits (least significant bits are taken).

For example, `8` is `1000` in binary, which leaves us with `000` after truncation to 3 bits. `-6` is `...1111010` in 2's-complement binary, which leaves us with `10` after truncation, which in turn is `-2`. And so on.